# How to mock the behavior of a database

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to test the functionality of persisting the data into elasticsearch using JUnits. This is the first time I am using JUnits and this is my first test case.

I have an interface which is like the below

```
public interface ElasticSearchIndexer {

    void writeTo(String inputJson) throws IOException;
}
```

The interface is implemented by multiple classes. The sample implementation looks like below

```
public class HardwareEOXIndexer implements ElasticSearchIndexer {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HardwareEOXIndexer.class);
    private final String es_index = "/hardwareeox/inv/";

    private String hostname;

    public HardwareEOXIndexer(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }

    public void writeTo(String inputJson) throws IOException {
        ReadContext ctx = JsonPath.parse(inputJson);
        String hardwareEOXId = Integer.toString(ctx.read("$.EoXBulletin.items[0].hardwareEOXId"));

        StringBuilder documentID = new StringBuilder().append(hardwareEOXId);
        logger.info("Indexing the document with ID :: {} ", documentID.toString());
        try {
            new ElasticSearchContext().getContext(hostname, inputJson, es_index, documentID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("HardwareEOXIndexer : es_index: " + es_index + " ------> " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

How do I mock the behavior of the elasticsearch and how to write unit tests.

Comment: A unit test for an interface (without default methods) does not make sense. You can only test an implementation of it.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *interface* part is bogus within the question, the core point is:

> How do I mock the behavior of the elasticsearch and how to write unit tests.

And there are basically two answers:

- you create an **abstraction** layer that hides the details of ElasticSearch. Meaning: instead of creating a new ElasticSearch object, you create an object of your own class (which you don't create via *new*, but via a factory object for example).
- you read about PowerMock, and how to use that to mock calls to `new`.

I definitely suggest you to go for the *first* option: simply because that will improve your design. You see, why do you want to *tightly couple* all of your code to elastic search? But assuming that this implementation is already meant as abstraction layer around elastic search - then you should still use **dependency injection** to acquire that `ElasticSearch` object you need to actually invoke methods on. As said, use a factory or a real DI framework. That will allow you to say with "simple" mocking frameworks such as Mockito or EasyMock.

Comment: There is also a third option (which I often use): inject a factory that hides the `new ElasticSearchContext()` behind a method that can then be mocked to return an `ElasticSearchContext` mock.

Comment: @MickMnemonic You are correct there, respectively: I wasn't fully precise when writing up my answer. I had that solution in mind as well.

Comment: I edited my question. I started off with the intention of understanding unit test cases for the interface and deviated by the database layer. Thanks for pointing.